# org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: null error al ejecutar edit.jsp

Tags: mysql, mvc, jsp, servlets

esta es la funcion editar

```
 public boolean edit(empleados emp) {
        String sql="update usuario set nom_usuario=?,apellido_usuario=?,"
                + "email=?,direccion=?,telefono_1=?,"
                + "telefono_2=?,contraseña=? where id_usuario=?";
        try {
            con=cn.getconexion();
            ps=con.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.executeUpdate();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    return false;
    }
```

este es el servlet que recibe los parametros es lo que ni me muestra cuando le doy editar.

```
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
        String acceso="";
        String action=request.getParameter("accion");
         if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("editar")) {
            request.setAttribute("idper", request.getParameter("id"));
            acceso=edit;
        }else if(action.equalsIgnoreCase("Actualizar")){
            int id=Integer.parseInt("ide");
            String nombre=request.getParameter("nombre");
            String apellido=request.getParameter("correo");
            String correo=request.getParameter("correo");
            String direccion=request.getParameter("direccion");
            String tel1=request.getParameter("tel1");
            String tel2=request.getParameter("tel2");
            String pass=request.getParameter("pass");
            em.setId(id);
            em.setNombre(nombre);
            em.setApellidos(apellido);
            em.setEmail(edit);
            em.setDireccion(direccion);
            em.setTel1(tel1);
            em.setTel2(tel2);
            em.setContraseña(correo);
            dao.edit(em);
            acceso=listar;
        }
        RequestDispatcher vista=request.getRequestDispatcher(acceso);
        vista.forward(request, response);
    }
```

y aqui el edit.jsp ya al intentar ejecutar este archivo me sale el erro mostrado arriba
pero si le doy al boton editar me lleva al servle pero me muestra en blanco la pagina ni el formulario no nada

```
                                <%
                                    empleadosDAO dao = new empleadosDAO();
                                    int id=Integer.parseInt((String)request.getAttribute("idper"));
                                    empleados em=(empleados)dao.list(id);                                   
                                %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Con el código que muestras (puesto que no podemos estar seguro de que el error no aparezca en otra parte),

```
(String)request.getAttribute("idper")
```

está devolviendo *null*.

¿Igual quieres hacer *request.getParameter("idper")*?

Comment: si, quiero capturar el atributo que instacie en el servelet "idper"   cuando ejecuto edit.jsp me dice que tengo error en esta linea  int 
 id=Integer.parseInt((String)request.getAttribute("idper"));

Comment: No me había fijado en esa parte del código. Eso parece correcto, deberías comprobar qué valor devuelve getParameter("id")

Comment: mira donde esta el error     SEVERE [31] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() para servlet REEmpleado lanzó excepción
 java.lang.NullPointerException
 at controlador.REEmpleado.doGet(REEmpleado.java:35) este es la linea  `if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("editar")) {`